# Secure sites to lock out administrator from reading files

Tags: sharepoint-server, item-level-permissions

This is an awkward question, but is it possible to lock out administrators from reading documents?

I know that you can individually encrypt documents, but are there any tools available to perform encryptions of folders to prevent reading from even administrators?

(this is primarily for confidential documents)

Comment: Are you referring to Site Collection Administrators?

Comment: Any administrator.

Comment: There's a difference between a site owner and a site collection administrator/site admin. Which do you mean?

Comment: ANY ADMINISTRATOR. Including farm admins and web app full access. I'm aware that everyone has full access, my main focus is on automated encryption tools

Comment: You can of course encrypt data and then upload it to SharePoint but these tools have nothing to do with SharePoint as a platform.

Answer (score 0):

Site collection administrators of a site have full access to all content and settings within that site. There is no way of reducing the site access of a site collection administrator.

With regards to farm administrators, they can grant themselves site collection administrator permission to any SharePoint site in the farm and therefore could have access to everything.

Typically, organisations will use audit logs in order to ensure that administrators have not accessed content without a good reason to do so.

Comment: "are there any tools available to perform encryptions of folders to prevent reading from even administrators?"

Comment: No, administrators have access to everything in a site, as already stated. You could encrypt data and upload it to SharePoint but these tools have nothing to do with SharePoint as a platform.

Comment: Additionally, there are no tools that perform encryptions of data "in place". You would need to have already encrypted the data and then upload it to SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to deploy an **AD RMS** server in your infrastructure and integrate it with SharePoint.
Then enable IRM protection with AD RMS on SharePoint library level.